# Loading result of SELECT statement into variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Consider following `FOR` loop:

```
FOR constraintInfo IN
  (SELECT table_name, column_name FROM user_cons_columns WHERE constraint_name = 'CNAME') LOOP ...
```

In the `FOR` loop I can then access `table_name` or `column_name` simply by `constraintInfo.table_name`. The advantage is that I don't have to specify the `constraintInfo`.

Now, I'd like to do similar thing, only this time loading one specific `SELECT` statement that always returns one row into a variable and then access it later on. I have tried with assigning `SELECT` statement directly into variable using `:=` and also using `SELECT ... INTO var`, however, these approaches either don't work or require me to already have defined a variable before.

My solution would be wrapping my whole code into a `FOR` loop since I know it will only run once (because only one row is always returned), but this doesn't sound as the best solution.

Would such a thing be possible? If so, how could I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a variable, just do

```
select somecolumn INTO yourVariable from someTable;
```

That alone will do the job just fine. Be aware that if the select doesn't work you will get a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.

And yes, you need to define the `yourVariable` first. But since you have tried with `some := select...` I take that it already exists.

To avoid the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception you can do as:

```
begin
  select somecolumn INTO yourVariable from someTable;
Exception
   when NO_DATA_FOUND then
    yourVariable:=null;
end;
```